# 400 Bad Request: unknown field 'type'

Tags: solr, sunspot

I've set up Solr 3.6.2 on Tomcat as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat).

Using the sunspot-rails gem and the embedded solr server I have no problems, but on my staging server I'm getting the response:

> **message** ERROR: [doc=Foo 20] unknown field 'type'
>
> **description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

The request data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">Foo 20</field>
    <field name="type">Foo</field>
    <field name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field>
    <field name="class_name">Foo</field>
    <field name="name">test</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

What's causing this?  Is there some configuration that should be set?  (I'm expecting something that allows for the `type` name to be used regardless of whether or not such a column exists.)

Comment: Hey There is already a solution for this problem -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340859/cant-reindex-sunspot-solr-error-rsolrerrorhttp-500-internal-server-er

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the sunspot-solr gem expects a slightly different `schema.xml` than the default that is bundled with `solr`.

I replaced the file with the one that the gem uses (from [here](https://raw.github.com/sunspot/sunspot/master/sunspot_solr/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml)) and it works fine now.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197139/684934) explains what the `schema.xml` file is.

Comment: where did you replace it? I am copying my schema generated in development to production server, `solr_dir/example/solr`. From example folder I run `java -jar start.jar`

Comment: Thank you! The schema.xml file that needs to be replaced lives in `<solr home>/<collection>/conf/schema.xml`

Comment: And don't forget to **restart** Solr **after altering** `schema.xml` !