# Solr not reindexing correctly - Sunspot Solr with Solr 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have a similar issue that [Solr with Rails - rake sunspot:reindex is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742142/solr-with-rails-rake-sunspotreindex-is-not-working).

I have these in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sunspot_solr', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
gem 'sunspot_rails', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
```

And:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

works fine, but when I do:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

I get:

```
Connection refused - {:data=>
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Service</query></delete>",
:headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby},
:query=>"wt=ruby", :path=>"update", :uri=>
#<URI::HTTP:0x007fccf982f348 URL:http://localhost:8982/solr/default/update?wt=ruby>,
:open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil,
:retry_after_limit=>nil}
```

Comment: could you check the corresponging Solr log to see what's going wrong at the server?

Comment: server is not being hit `tail -f log/sunspot-solr-development.log` changes in Solr start(I am seeing correct log) but does not change on reindex.

Comment: I suppose `localhost:8982` is by design? Default port is `8983`?

Comment: prod 8983, dev 8982, test 8981. I am currently using dev and test, I can access to admin console in dev and test.

Comment: ahh - now am out of ideas, I'm afraid.

Comment: I made some progress.. updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added path to sunspot.yml

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

Not sure if this good enough though. Seems this is because I am using Solr 4 and configuration is creating `solr/environment` type URLs.