# Problems with sunspot(solr)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have model ShopItem
I'm using sunspot and solr.
At development I use *sunspot_solr* gem, in production I configured server with this manual: http://www.arborisoft.com/how-to-install-multicore-apache-solr-4-7-on-debian-7/

<del>Here is what I get at ptoduction, in dev everything is OK</del>
<del>*Some logs, which are unnecessary now*</del>

My ShopItem model

```
  searchable do
    text :title, boost: 3.0
    # ColorShopItem
    text :colors, boost: 2.0 do
      colors.map {|c| [c.color.title, c.color.hex] }
    end
    text :materials, boost: 2.0 do
      request_parameter.materials
    end
    text :country, boost: 1.0 do
      request_parameter.address.try(:country).try(:title)
    end
    text :state, boost: 1.0 do
      request_parameter.address.try(:state)
    end
    text :city, boost: 1.0 do
      request_parameter.address.try(:city)
    end
    boolean :published
  end
```

**UPD**: Promblems were in that */opt/solr/staging/multicore/staging/conf/schema.xml* wasn't updated with `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`
So there is another question: **How to update this file using this command?**

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`?

Comment: Not working.
Maybe there are problems with rights, but I work as root(I know it's bad, but it's staging)

Comment: I don't remember how solr works (used it last time long time ago), but does it modifiys schema.xml? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195894/how-does-sunspot-modify-solrs-schema-xml-does-it-modify-it-at-all